# npm Modules installed without consent

Tags: node.js, module, npm

When I check the \AppData\Roaming\npm-cache folder on my Windows7 computer, I saw many node modules which were installed without my consent (I didn't know those modules were installed on my computer). Is there any possibility to get a Log of the modules which installed along with dependencies? It is possible to check the package.json for dependencies, but checking the package.json recursively in sub folders is a bit difficult job.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
npm shrinkwrap
```

It will give you a .json file with a snapshot of all the dependencies required for your project, all the way down. From that you can extract all the modules (with versions) that will be added to your cache (assuming this is the only node project installed on your machine).

It should be noted that all modules publicly list their dependencies via their package.json files. If you are uncomfortable installing unknown software on your machine, you can use these files to locate the code and check what each requires as dependencies.

To avoid further frustration you should read the documentation. Specifically:

- [npm install](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/install.html)
- [folders used by npm](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html)
- [the npm cache](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-cache.html)

Comment: Assuming 'I have installed only one Node app' doesnt make any sense, because it is not the case most of the time. Also, I can see the cached list in  \AppData\Roaming\npm-cache folder without any additional module.

Comment: If you have multiple projects installed, then the set of modules in the cache is obviously the union of all modules required to run them. My assumption was for clarity only.

Comment: Please read the links in the updated answer. npm has not installed anything without your permission. npm is a short for *node package manager*, and it keeps a cache to avoid hitting npmjs.org for packages more often than necessary. For a free service, I think that's fair enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I can agree that npm is not installing anything without 'user' permission. because...
When we install a module, the average user might only check the immediate **package.json** but npm will load all the other dependent internal modules too. Thats what I am concerning.

Comment: It is the nature of npm to work on a tree of dependencies. This is fundamental, and not knowing this means that you haven't taken the time to familiarise yourself with npm before using it. The onus is upon you to check this if you are concerned about what gets installed on your system. Nothing is hidden, it is all documented. How else could you know about this?